# Rails model method: which is preferable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am able to pass my model tests with two different approaches. Which is preferable? What approaches can I take to  determine which is preferable, or if one is preferable?

```
def queued_video?(video)
  queue_items.where(video: video.id).present?
end
```

vs

```
def queued_video?(video)
  queue_items.map(&:video).include?(video)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that `queued_items` is an `ActivreRecord` query.

I would not prefer the second because it evaluates all `queue_items`. The first is more efficient.

You can use `any?` instead of `present?` to make it feel more natural.

I think your best option is to use the [`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) method of `ActiveRecord`

```
def queued_video(video)
  queue_items.exists?(video: video.id)
end
```

which results in a `select 1` query

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM `table_name` WHERE `table_name`.`video_id` = 123 LIMIT
```

and does exactly what you need in a more elegant way.

Comment: I agree this is the right answer in most cases. One argument for the other solution would be that it doesn't need to hit the database if all the involved records are already loaded, so it may be the better choice under certain circumstances. If you did go with the other one, it could be simplified to `queue_items.any? { |i| i.video == video }` or `queue_items.any? { |i| i.video_id == video.id }` depending on whether the video records are loaded or not.